# Filtering Mongoose document that contains array of object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, filter

I would like to know how to retrieve documents in MongoDB using mongoose that all have the value true for the "done" property inside an array of objects.
Something like this : 
this one should be found :

```
    _id : xxxx,
    step:
    [{name : "step1", done : true},
    {name : "step2", done : true},
    {name : "step3", done : true}
    {name : "step4", done : true}
    ]
    otherProperty : "random string ...",
    ...,
    __v : 0
```

```
------
```

this one should be ignored

```
    _id : xxxx,
    step:
    [{name : "step1", done : true},
    {name : "step2, done : true},
    {name : "step3", done : false}
    {name : "step4", done : true}
    ]
    otherProperty : "random string ...",
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The following code will get all the documents from the MongoDB Collection, iterate over them to check which one's have all the steps done successfully, and then print the ones that have completed all the steps.

```
const mongoose = require( "mongoose" );
const Schema   = mongoose.Schema;
const Model    = mongoose.model;

const StepSchema = new Schema({
    step: [Object],
    name: String
});


Step = Model( "Step", StepSchema );

mongoose.connect( "mongodb://localhost:27017/chummy", { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true } );

Step.find( {}, (err, docs) => {  // Get all the documents from the COllection.

    docs.forEach(doc => {  // Select the documents one by one.

        let success = true; // Set a variable that will tell whether the document completed all the steps or not.

        doc.step.forEach( s => {  // Select each step one by one.
            if(!s.done == true) {  // Check if the step was done or not e.g. s.done = true
                success = false;    // If the step was not done, then change success to false.
                return; // Since a step failed, there's no need to continue checking the rest.
            }
        } );

        if(success) {     // Check if success is still true.
            console.log(doc);  // If all the steps were completed, success will stay true and the document will be logged.
        }

    });

} );
```

*Note: This is all the code, and this code was tested on Ubuntu 19.04 Desktop with NodeJS 10.16.3, NPM 6.9.0, and Mongoose 5.7.5*

Answer (score 0):

try in this way

```js
 let data = [{_id : 'xxxx',
    step:
    [{name : "step1", done : true},
    {name : "step2", done : true},
    {name : "step3", done : true},
    {name : "step4", done : true}
    ],
    __v : 0
  },{_id : 'xxxx',
    step:
    [{name : "yuty", done : true},
    {name : "step2", done : false},
    {name : "step3", done : true},
    {name : "step4", done : true}
    ],
    __v : 0
  }];
let finalDta = data.filter(d=>
  !d.step.map(done=>done.done).includes(false)
)
console.log(finalDta)
```

Comment: i have added it in wrong way before but now it fulfill your requirement